# Relabeling of subsubsequences

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Often, when extracting subsequences of a subsequence, we avoid the cumbersome notation with a tower of indices by relabeling them. I wondered which way is more correct, formally. Say we have $x_n$, and we extract $x_{n_j}$ and then further extract $x_{n_{j_k}}$. I want to relabel the last one as a subsequence of $x_n$. Is it more correct to use $x_{n_k}$ or to change altogether the index and use, say, $x_{n_l}$? Clearly one can always invoke dummy indices, and do whatever, but which notation is preferred? I once heard a professor expressing a strong preference for one, but I cannot recall which. Thanks for any help.

Comment: For me, double subscripts represents the boundary of what I can easily understand at a glance, which I feel should be the goal of communication.  So, for me, $\displaystyle x_{n_k}~$ is fine, but $~\displaystyle x_{n_{k_r}}~$ is not.  So, when forced to index a sub-subsequence, I would define $~\displaystyle f(n,k,r) = n_{k_r},~$ and then refer to $~\displaystyle x_{f(n,k,r)}.$

Comment: My vague recollection is that this professor preferred $x_{n_l}$ to avoid some sort of confusion arising from keeping the same letter ($k$) as the last index, but I am not sure what is confusing about that to be honest, and I also find very natural to use $x_{n_k}$.

Comment: My comment wasn't intended to express a preference for which variables were used to represent the subscripts.  Instead, I was expressing a preference for limiting the **depth of the subscripts**.  I can understand $~x_{n_r},~$ which is only two levels deep, at a glance.  So, that is okay for me.  My problem would be with deeper levels of subscripts, such as $x_{n_{r_s}}.$

Comment: I see, I totally agree with that.

Comment: @GGG: For me $k$ isn't a problem, but $l$ is because it could be mistaken for $1.$ Thus, I never (that I'm aware of) use $l$ for a subscript, and rarely use $l$ in general. Indeed, if variables/constants are involved and I want to use 3 or 4 in alphabetic order AND if I feel the need to include $l,$ then I'll probably resort to using upper-case letters.

Comment: I just used $l$ to mean a letter different from $k$, could be anything, if I recall the discussion correctly and its main point. But I see from your comment, and the previous one, that using the same letter $k$ is generally accepted, thank you for sharing your opinion.